# NSGA ii algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I need to compare an algorithm that a wrote with NSGA ii algorithm, so I want to know the complexity of NSGA ii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All major complexities of the algorithm are discussed in the original NSGA-ii paper [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=996017). If you do not have the subscription to IEEE TEC journal, then you can access the corresponding technical report [here](http://vision.ucsd.edu/~sagarwal/nsga2.pdf). The abstract of the paper mentions the time complexity of the most expensive part of the algorithm (ignoring (assuming-small) the time complexity involved in evaluating the objective functions) as O(MN^2) where M is number of objectives and N is the population size.